Is there an alternative for using symlinks to enable a 3rd-party dll to access a xml file that can be edited by an app without admin rights?
I've a .NET app that doesn't ask for Admin rights, but is installed under Program Files. The app can use a 3rd-party DLL that requires a xml config file located in the same folder as the DLL. The xml file, in turn, can be configured according to some settings that are unique to each user and are set from the app itself.
The issue is that while the user can change the settings from the app, it returns a "Access Denied" exception when trying to save the xml file, as expected.
The workaround I found was to create a symlink to AppData during installation, since my installer requests Admin rights, so that the dll is tricked into reading from an accessible location.
Is this the best solution or have I missed a more elegant one?
